# Draw a line over another line using google maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, cordova

I want to track a car on the road using the javascript Google map API. So that I used this function to change the car location:

```
function getDrivingRoute(myLatlng, arrival) {
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googlemaps"), mapOptions);
startMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position : myLatlng,
    map : map,
    icon : '../images/taxii.png'
});
var stopMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position : arrival,
    map : map,
    icon : 'icon-1.png'
});

directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
directionsDisplay.setOptions({
    suppressMarkers : true,
    polylineOptions : {
        strokeWeight : 3,
        strokeOpacity : 0.7,
        strokeColor : 'green'
    }
});
request = {
    origin : myLatlng,
    destination : arrival,
    travelMode : google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
};
directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
});
var i = 0;
// var addr1=new google.maps.LatLng('35.8416079','10.5983287');
var addr2 = new google.maps.LatLng('35.8423558', '10.5986720');
var addr3 = new google.maps.LatLng('35.8425124', '10.5992299');
var addr4 = new google.maps.LatLng('35.8423558', '10.5997664');
var addr5 = new google.maps.LatLng('35.8420775', '10.6006032');
var position_driver = [ addr2, addr3, addr4, addr5 ];
var myVar = setInterval(
        function() {
            myLatlng = position_driver[i];

            if (myLatlng.lat() == arrival.lat()
                    && myLatlng.lng() == arrival.lng()) {
                changePosition(myLatlng.lat(), myLatlng.lng());
                window.clearInterval(myVar);


            } else {

            startMarker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(myLatlng.lat(), myLatlng.lng());
            }
            i++;
        }, 8000);

}
```

The car marker change its position and get the right position on the map, but the route line doesn't change, I want to disappear the travelled distance or show it with another color and show the non travelled distance with different color. Is that possible? I tried to override the existing line with another but it doesn't shows.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to overwrite you path with different color with new polyline

```
 var reRouteOptions = {
        path: position_driver.getPath(),
        strokeColor: 'grey',
        strokeWeight: 1
    };
    var reRoute = new google.maps.Polyline(reRouteOptions);
    reRoute.setMap(map);
```

Comment: It shows a  straight line between the position I have set. if I have a non linear road what should I do then?

Comment: Shouldn't your position_driver contain all your points for your polyline?

Comment: No not all, it contains my actual position and my position 1 min ago.